# How to set an alarm/event or notification if AWS-ECS perticular task is terminated

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have a specific requirement in my project for `AWS ECS task`.
We have an `ECS Task` which is scheduled on 7 AM and running successfully and it happens if the task is terminated due to some error or someone purposefully terminates it, we need to raise an notification or alert which will let some peoples know that the task is terminated.

Need some help regarding this

for the same thing achieved I have followed below steps using `AWS` documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwet2.html

a. created event for `ECS Task State Change` using `AWS cloudwatch`
b. provided below event pattern

```
   {  
    "source":[  
    "aws.ecs"
    ],
   "detail-type":[  
     "ECS Task State Change"
    ],
  "detail":{  
    "clusterArn":[  
    "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/nonprod-ECS-ECSCluster-xxxxxxxxxx"
     ],
     "lastStatus":[  
      "RUNNING"
     ],
    "desiredStatus":[  
     "STOPPED"
     ],
    "taskDefinitionArn":[  
    "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:task-definition/ecs-task:37"
     ],
    "containerInstanceArn":[
     "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:container-instance/XXXXXXXXXXX-2c61-43db-8fbc-XXXXXXXXXXX"
     ]
  }
```

}

b. created `SNS` topic subscription to mail id
c. Added target and provided `SNS` details
d. executed `ECS task` and terminated/stopped it immediately.
e. Failed to get the notification.